# Draggable scroll to right don't have padding

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

My issues have on a draggable scroll widget when I suing draggable_widget 2.0.0 I can draggable scroll to AnchoringPosition normal, but when I try draggable to right it's overflow and if I draggable scroll to left it have padding normal, so everyone ever meet the issue like me when you are using draggable_widget 2.0.0

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dragController.showWidget();
                  },
                  child: Text("Show"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dragController.hideWidget();
                  },
                  child: Text("Hide"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dragController.jumpTo(AnchoringPosition.topRight);
                  },
                  child: Text("Move to Top Right"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dragController.jumpTo(AnchoringPosition.topLeft);
                  },
                  child: Text("Move to Top Left"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dragController.jumpTo(AnchoringPosition.bottomRight);
                  },
                  child: Text("Move to bottom Right"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dragController.jumpTo(AnchoringPosition.bottomLeft);
                  },
                  child: Text("Move to Bottom Left"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dragController.jumpTo(AnchoringPosition.center);
                  },
                  child: Text("Move to Center"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          DraggableWidget(
            bottomMargin: 80,
            topMargin: 80,
            intialVisibility: true,
            horizontalSpace: 20,
            shadowBorderRadius: 50,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.close), onPressed: () {})
                ],
              ),
            ),
            initialPosition: AnchoringPosition.bottomLeft,
            dragController: dragController,
          )
        ],
      ),
```

I'm expecting while I try draggable to right not overflow it's should be have bedding like draggable scroll to left. Thanks.